# Modifier issue in Cycles - Black Ghosting

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, transparency

I'm fairly new to Blender and was hoping you could help.

I'm creating a short animation for a University project and have come up against an issue.

I'm creating an animation where a sphere splits in half. Either side of the sphere is a separate shape. A shader is used to gradually make them transparent to give the feeling they are vanishing.

There is also an Array modifier applied to either side to give the feeling there are multiple spheres inside. The issue I'm having is when the shader removes the shape. It leaves a black shape where the modifier was.

I've tried troubleshooting myself. At first, I thought it was because Cycles couldn't calculate all the light bounces, but it still happens with the Array set to 1. I thought the shader was not interacting with the modifier, so I tried a Boolean to remove the shape gradually. This didn't work either. I also tried playing around with the Alpha mode of the material which gets it to work in Eeevee but does not affect Cycles.

[image: Here is a view of it in Cycles]

[image: and another in Eeevee where it actually works]

Here is a link to where you can download the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZoFcQ6YbOK4teLA0KJbSaMIzYOqEgesO/view?usp=sharing

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: The renders are too dark to tell exactly what is going on or what it’s supposed to look like. Maybe add solid view screenshots instead?

Comment: Hey my bad, it doesn't show in solid view as it's only in Cycles where the issue lies. Here is an image where you can better see the problem - https://imgur.com/jTRIqs0

Comment: "Instead" was a bad choice. I need the Solid view renders to see what the scene even is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an array can easily create more surfaces than there are allowed transparent bounces. Eevee doesn't really care, since it's less optimized in that regard. Material options don't really affect Cycles renderings. Anyways, bump up the transparent bounces and you should be fine.
[image]

If not, share a screenshot of the material and I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: Frederik this works perfectly. Thank you so, so much for the help - I was really stuck! Hope you have a great week.

Comment: Thanks, could you please upvote and accept the answer, so others only need to look at the thread if they have the same problem?

Comment: Sure thing. Apologies I'm new to the forum, thanks for explaining.